# How to refer to an image from the Images.xcassets folder

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

Here is my code that does not work. I tried first to load the image from file, now I am using a named image:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIImage *imageYouWantToPass = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bl_5_00"];

    self.mainImage.image = imageYouWantToPass;
}
```

If I put an image in the Images.xcassets folder should the above code work? In other words, if the image is not showing, it is due to a mistake elsewhere in my code?

Comment: Is the image you are trying to load a PNG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That image should work if you have a group in 'Images.xcassets'. It's case sensitive too so beware. If you just drag and drop the images into the folder, that could be a problem. Click on the .xcassets file in XCode, create a new Image Set and put the image in the boxes.

Comment: Is the group required? I added this code: NSLog(@"%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bl_5_00" ofType:@"png"]); and it prints null.

Comment: What I meant was create an 'Image Set' and then you can reference it through code. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html

Comment: Yes, the Image Set is required, you can't just drag the image into the .xcassets and have it found.